# function to open a main GUI using a button from a PopUp GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I am new to Python, trying to make the <kbd>Launch TFL App</kbd> button open another GUI called "Menu GUI" but I don't know what to do for the `def open_Menu():` function below. I want to use the popup GUI below as a launcher which takes the user to my main GUI. The only problem with the code below is that the button for <kbd>launch TFL app</kbd> doesn't do anything when you click it.
Here's my current code :

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

root.title('TFL App')

p = Label(root, text = "TFL Journey Planner", height = "18", width = "250", bg = 'brown', fg = 
'white',
      font = ('Helvetica', '20', 'bold', 'italic'))
p.pack()
root.configure(bg = 'brown')
root.geometry('400x700')

photo = PhotoImage(file = 'trainstation.png')
label = Label(root, image = photo)

label.pack()


****#Buttons****

def open_Menu():
    pass
    

Button1 = Button(root, text = "Launch TFL App", command = open_Menu, bg = "black", fg = 'white', padx 
 = 40,
             pady = 10,
             font = ('Calibri Light', '15', 'bold'))
Button1.pack(padx = 25, pady = 0)


Button2 = Button(root, text = "Exit ", command = root.destroy, bg = "black", fg = 'white', padx = 65, 
pady = 8,
             font = ('Calibri Light', '15', 'bold'))
Button2.pack(padx = 25, pady = 10)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I implement `open_menu()`

The code below is for my Main GUI which should open through the PopUp GUI above but the button on the PopUp GUI is not working.

```
from tkinter import *

def find():
# get method returns current text
# as a string from text entry box
    From = From_field.get()
    To = To_field.get()
    travel_modes = mode_field.get()

# Calling result() Function
result(From, To, travel_modes)


# Function for inserting the train string
# in the mode_field text entry box
def train():
    mode_field.insert(10, "train")


# Function for clearing the contents

def del_From():
    From_field.delete(0, END)
    distance_field.delete(0, END)
    duration_field.delete(0, END)


def del_To():
    To_field.delete(0, END)
    distance_field.delete(0, END)
    duration_field.delete(0, END)


def del_modes():
    mode_field.delete(0, END)
    distance_field.delete(0, END)
    duration_field.delete(0, END)



def delete_all():
    From_field.delete(0, END)
    To_field.delete(0, END)
    mode_field.delete(0, END)
    distance_field.delete(0, END)
    duration_field.delete(0, END)


# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
# Create a GUI root
root = Tk()

# Set the background colour of GUI root
root.configure(background = 'light blue')

# Set the configuration of GUI root
root.geometry("600x400")

# Created a welcome to distance time calculator label
headlabel = Label(root, text = 'Welcome to your TFL Journey Planner',
                  fg = 'white', bg = "dark red", height = "0", width = "30",
                  font = ('calibri light', '19', 'italic'))

# Created a From: label
label1 = Label(root, text = "From:",
               fg = 'white', bg = 'black')

# Created a To: label
label2 = Label(root, text = "To:",
               fg = 'white', bg = 'black')

# Created a Distance: label
label4 = Label(root, text = "Distance:",
               fg = 'white', bg = 'black')

# Created a Duration: label
label5 = Label(root, text = "Duration:",
               fg = 'white', bg = 'black')

label6 = Label(root, text = "Choose travelling mode Below: ",
               fg = 'white', bg = 'black')

headlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
label1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "E")
label2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "E")
label4.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = "E")
label5.grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = "E")
label6.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

# Created a text entry box
# for filling or typing the data.
From_field = Entry(root)
To_field = Entry(root)
mode_field = Entry(root)
distance_field = Entry(root)
duration_field = Entry(root)

From_field.grid(row = 1, column = 1, ipadx = "100")
To_field.grid(row = 2, column = 1, ipadx = "100")
mode_field.grid(row = 5, column = 1, ipadx = "50")
distance_field.grid(row = 7, column = 1, ipadx = "100")
duration_field.grid(row = 8, column = 1, ipadx = "100")

# CLEAR Button and attached
# to del_source function
button1 = Button(root, text = "Clear", bg = "light grey",
                 fg = "black", command = del_From)

# Create a CLEAR Button and attached to del_destination
button2 = Button(root, text = "Clear", bg = "light grey",
                 fg = "black", command = del_To)

# Create a RESULT Button and attached to find function
button3 = Button(root, text = "Result",
                 bg = "black", fg = "white",
                 command = find)

# Create a CLEAR ALL Button and attached to delete_all function
button4 = Button(root, text = "Clear All",
                 bg = "light grey", fg = "black",
                 command = delete_all)

# Create a Train Button and attached to train function
button5 = Button(root, text = "Train",
                 bg = "light grey", fg = "black",
                 command = train)

# Create a CLEAR Button and attached to del_modes function
button6 = Button(root, text = "Clear",
                 fg = "black", bg = "light grey",
                 command = del_modes)

button1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
button2.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
button3.grid(row = 6, column = 1)
button4.grid(row = 9, column = 1)
button5.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
button6.grid(row = 5, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is Menu Gui or perhaps are you looking for Menu Widget

Comment: the menu is my main Gui, I can post the code for that if you want.

Comment: I want to use the popup GUI above as a launcher which takes the user to my main GUI. The only problem with the code above is that the button for "launch TFL app" doesn't do anything when you click it.

Comment: Please do so, but please explain your problem. My guess is, do you want to open a GUI window from a button in another GUI window

Comment: Then take look at Toplevel widget that might help

Comment: One of the ways is using `subprocess.Popen()` to execute the "Main GUI" script inside `open_Menu()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `from subprocess import call`. All you have to do is replace 'YOUR_FILE_NAME' with... your file name :D

```
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import call

root=Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(pady=20,padx=20)

def open_Menu():
    call(["python", "YOUR-FILE-NAME.py"])

btn=Button(frame,text='Open File',command=Open)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What it will look like:

[image]

I hope this works for you :D

Comment: Glad to help! Good Luck on your project :D